# iOS 5 UIButtons in UIScrollView not clickable

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uibutton

I've got a strange bug whereby two UIButtons inside a UIView, which is in turn inside a UIScrollView view are not clickable on iOS 5, but work perfectly fine on iOS 6 (screenshot shows scroller and map underneath)

The only other detail is the scroller view 'slides up' to reveal buttons when a station is selected. I've tried selecting the buttons on iOS 5, and they do get hit (visually), but the event isn't fired.

**Edit**: If I tap and hold on the button in the simulator, then move the cursor up the screen and release (e.g. to the part of the UIView that was always visible), the event fires.

[image: Scroller Sample]

The scroll view itself has the following settings, the latter two have only been added in order to try and make the buttons work on iOS 5 (tried various combinations):

```
self.scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
self.scrollView.delaysContentTouches = NO;
self.scrollView.canCancelContentTouches = NO;
```

The button events are all wired up correctly, with suitable targets etc:

```
[_updatePriceButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showPriceUpdateBoxWithPrice:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[_stationDetailsButton addTarget:self action:@selector(stationDetailsSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

And handlers (here's one as a sample):

```
- (void)stationDetailsSelected:(id)sender {
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(stationDetailsSelected:)]) {
        [self.delegate stationDetailsSelected:_station];
    }
}
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: Is the UIView that contains the buttons actually high enough to fully hold the buttons? If that is not the case, touch events might not reach them. Quick way to find out is to give the view a background color.

Comment: Yeah, seems to be - gave it a lovely green colour and it included the buttons. The UIView itself was built with interface builder.

Comment: Just want to confirm:  `userInteractionEnabled = YES`, correct?

Comment: Yeah, tried on the UIView within the UIScrollView. Anything else I need to add that's iOS 5 specific?

Comment: What happens if you enable `clipsToBounds` on all views between the top layer and the buttons — not just the scroll view?

Comment: Hmm, no such luck. I did notice something strange though - if I tap hold over the button in the simulator, then release the mouse outside of the button, it fires the event?

Comment: Good questions here in comments.  Here's a couple more: do the buttons work as children of the main view?  How about placing their containing view outside the scroll view on the main view - do they work then?  9 times out of 10 in these situations, it's nib constraints resizing something that leaves children outside of their parent view bounds.

Answer (score 6):

Found the culprit - a misconfigured UITapGestureRecognizer on the UIView the UIButtons sit on:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(stationInfoViewTapped:)];
[infoController.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

Simply adding the following after init of 'tap' solves the issue in iOS 5:

```
[tap setCancelsTouchesInView:NO];
```